# What does (.:format) refer to in Rails and how does it interact with the _path and _url helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been writing my routes manually but gave up after realizing how pointless that would be in Rails given that a large part of the purpose of this framework is automating repetition.

After generating my routes using Rails' `resources` keyword, I'm unable to find any explicit documentation explaining what the `(.:format)` parameter represents. I'm also unclear on how `_path` and `_url` helpers engage these routes:

```
posts     GET    /posts(.:format)              posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format) posts#create
new_post  GET    /posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
post      GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)            posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)            posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)            posts#destroy
```

Answer (score 6):

The parenthesis denote an optional bound parameter in the pattern. It's saying that if there is a dot in the URL followed by some text, that will become available as `params[:format]`, but that is optional for the route to be matched.

That means that the URL can pass in the format:

```
GET /posts
GET /posts.json
GET /posts.pdf
GET /posts.xml
```

The default is understood to be `html`.

When building a URL with a `_path` or `_url` helper, you can pass the format as another value for the URL:

```
# href will be /posts.json
link_to 'Posts JSON', posts_path(:json)

# href will be /posts/1234.json
link_to @post.title, post_path(@post, :json)
```

In the controller, you can respond to these formats in different ways:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # This will render `index.html.erb` automatically

    format.json { render json: @posts }

    format.csv do
      # Do some CSV stuff here
    end
  end
end
```

The section on [Bound Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) in the guides sort of mentions the function of parenthesis in a roundabout way:

> since `:action` and `:id` are optional parameters, denoted by parentheses.

This is referring to the example route:

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot chris!

Answer (score 4):

Those are the standard routes generated by a Rails `resources` helper in the routes file.

`(.:format)` refers to a variable/parameter you can pass to the helper that will turn the request into the format defined:

```
/posts.json # will handle the requests as JSON
/posts  # will handle the request as the default, html.
```

You can read more about this in "[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)".